# Exchange 2010 Search-Mailbox SearchQuery with ### on the subject

Tags: exchange-2010, search

I'm trying to search for messages that include "###" on the subject. I'm checking the AQS [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965711%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but can't see how to escape characters. I've tried quoting, double quoting, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Is this about Exchange Server 2010 or Windows Desktop Search?

Comment: It's about Exchange 2010 which also uses AQS, I've changed the question title to clarify

Answer (score 1):

This is a little late but I've run into the same issues and found this to be helpful and pertain to the issues. https://superuser.com/questions/168638/trouble-trying-to-use-windows-search-to-search-for-file-with-a-question-mark-in.

In summary to the link above. The search seems to ignore the special characters and searches based on words only.

I've tested by sending two separate emails with the **subjects**, **"Having ### in subject"** and **"Having in subject"**

The **query** I constructed looks like **-SearchQuery "Subject:`"Having ### in subject`""**

The search using this query yielded 2 results finding both subjects which did ignore the '###' all together.  This also seems to hold true even when symbols are part of the word such as **queries** like **"Having### in subject"** and **"Having###in subject"**.

If you are single using single quotes in the subject then you would escape the **query** like: **-SearchQuery "Subject:'Having ### in subject'"** but this too ignores the symbols and will return results for both **subjects** **"Having ### in subject"** and **"Having in subject"**.

Comment: Thanks, as far as I can tell, there's just no way to do a search like this